# Accessing post id from show in orders/new view and orders/create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have checkout using braintree api located at orders/new. However, the price that I want to charge the user is determined based on what the post id is. The user is linked to orders/new from the posts/show if that helps at all.
thanks in advance!

Accessing the :post_id in the create method is a little trickier because there is no link to a create view to send the :post_id with.

orders_controller create method

```
def create
    post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
    nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
    render action: :new and return unless nonce
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
    amount: post.price,
    payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )
  end
end
```

orders new view that sends user to the create method

```
<h2>Purchase Ticket (refresh if fields don't load)</h2>
<p>the price is <%= number_to_currency(@post.price) %></p>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<%= render 'payment/form' %>
```

When using this updated top section of my form

```
<%= form_tag orders_path, method: 'post' do %>
  <%= hidden_field :post_id, @post.id %>
  <div id="dropin"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay">
<% end %>
<%= @params %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `post_id` into the link on the `post#show` view that points to the `orders#new` action:

```
<%= link_to 'Purchase', new_order_path(post_id: @post.id) %>
```

In your orders controller you will also need to allow the `post_id` to be accepted by the strong params section:

```
def post_params
  params.permit(:post_id)
end
```

I do not know what is already in you `orders_params` method so I have given you the minimum that should work from the [guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html%23strong-parameters).

Then in the `OrdersController` action you can grab the `post_id` from the params:

```
def new
  post_id = post_params[:post_id]
  # ...
end
```

**UPDATE:** expanding answer to encompass additional create action criteria.

Maybe the most straight forward option is to add a hidden field in the form to store the `post_id`:

```
# app/views/payments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_tag orders_path, method: 'post' do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, @post.id %>
  <div id="dropin"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay">
<% end %>
```

This will mean that the `post_id` you put into the `link_to` method argument on the post will be stored in the form and be submitted to the create action, and you can access it in the same way:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.find(post_params[:post_id])
  end

  def create
    post = Post.find(post_params[:post_id])
    render text: post.price # to demonstrate
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.permit(:post_id)
  end
end
```

I have put together a quick [demo application](https://github.com/the-undefined/so-answer-demo-27918025) to show the working code.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can access it from the params inside of the action :-)

Comment: Using the same principles yes, you can pass the :post_id key and value to any link_to helper method as above. If the code worked for you would you mind marking this as the answer? If you add more context around the create action use case in your question then I can update the answer if it would help:-)

Comment: It's OK I wasn't holding an upvote for ransom ;-) I have expanded the answer to encompass the additional criteria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68806/discussion-between-the-undefined-and-belowaverageprogrammer).